# Is it possible to block flash at the firewall without SSL interception?

Tags: firewall

I want to block flash in our network. It can of cause be done through group policies on a host level but this will not affect flash installations that are included in products that aren't centrally managed.

The solution most mentioned is to block flash by the content type `application/x-shockwave-flash` but this will only work with HTTP traffic as Im not allowed to intercept SSL traffic. Is there a way to block flash without intercepting SSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word: *NO*

If you aren't decoding the SSL stream, you have no idea what's in it.